# Material table datasource filter with column value - ERROR matColumnDef

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a normal Angular Material  DataTable with sort headers. Thats work correctly in my other component but now I faced this error I don't know where is the problem
here is my code :

**component.ts**

```
headElements = ['ID', 'Name', 'Description'];
  OrdonnanceList : OrdonnanceInfo[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['ID', 'Name', 'Description','icons'];
  ordonnances : OrdonnanceInfo;
  id : string;

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.OrdonnanceList);

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private ordonnaceService : OrdonnanceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

**component.html**

```
 <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
      <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef>Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.nom_medicament}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

**error**

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/table/cell.d.ts:42:5 - error TS2610: 'name' is defined as an accessor in class 'CdkColumnDef', but is overridden here in 'MatColumnDef' as an instance property.

42     name: string;
   ~~~~
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the column name from "Name" to "MedName"?

Comment: Yeah I change it but still not working still the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR in node\_modules/@angular/material/table/cell.d.ts -Typescript version problem angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083915/error-in-node-modules-angular-material-table-cell-d-ts-typescript-version-prob)

Comment: @Scratte yeah it is