# ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/table/cell.d.ts -Typescript version problem angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, tslint

Im using angular in my project so I faced this issue I tried to downgrade my typscript to 3.9.7 but still not working  here is my **package.json** dpendencies.

```
    "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/typescript": "^2.0.0-5d0e199",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^4.0.0",
```

can someone give me an idea to solve this issue
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed material folder and I install npm install @angular/material@^10.1.3 and downgrade @angular/core to 10.1.3
I created new project with the latest version of angular and I copy the cell.d.ts file and paste it in my project & thats working now

Answer (score 10):

For me a reinstall with the latest versions helped:

```
npm remove @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm i @angular/material@latest @angular/cdk@latest
```

Replace npm with yarn in case you have yarn.

Comment: Keep in mind that this might result in breaking peer dependencies since this can upgrade to a new major version but will not check your peer dependencies like "ng update" does.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

For more information follow the link: https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/2501#issuecomment-960650663

Answer (score 1):

If you have npm version 8, try downgrading to an older version. It fixed the problem for me.