# When i try to run my angular app i am getting overwrite error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I create simple angular app, but when i serve it during building i am getting below error:

```
'value' is defined as an accessor in class 'MatSlider', but is overridden here in 'MatSliderProgressBarComponent' as an instance property.


value: number;
```

Do you have any idea what causing this error? Appreciate for all answers

Comment: Try to look at the answers in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083915/error-in-node-modules-angular-material-table-cell-d-ts-typescript-version-prob)

Comment: i tried all answers on that page but did not work for me